# Ephymeral ports range and tw buckets

Tags: tcp, port, sysctl

Should value of net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets be lower than the range set with net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range?

And if no, why they doesn't conflicts?

Thanks